# Trying to mock an http client that is inside a controller, using phpunit, but it doesn't work

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, guzzle

I have to test the routes of a controller which uses Guzzle Wrapper as a client to get data from an API. The app uses Laravel as a framework.

This is the part of the code that gives me trouble in the controller's function I am currently testing:

```
public function addContacts(Request $request)
{
   ...
   $client = new GuzzleWrapper();
   $response = $client->post($uri, $data);
   if($response->getStatusCode() != 200) { 
      return response()->json("Problem getting data", 500);
   }
   ...
}
```

Now, what I have tried are
getMockBuilder:

```
$mock = getMockBuilder(GuzzleWrapper::class)->onlyMethods(array('post'))->getMock();
$mock->expects($this->once())->method('post')->willReturn(response()->json([$responseData], 200));
```

Http::fake :

```
Http::fake(
   [$uri => Http::response([$responseData], 200)
);
```

Mockery :

```
$mockGuzzleClient = Mockery::mock(GuzzleWrapper::class);
$mockGuzzleClient->shouldReceive('post')
->andReturn(response()->json([$responseData], 200));
```

I also tried Mockery like this:

```
$mockGuzzleClient = Mockery::mock(GuzzleWrapper::class, function (MockInterface $mock){
   $mock->shouldReceive('post')
   ->andReturn(response()->json([$responseData], 200));
});
```

And like this:

```
$this->app->instance(
   GuzzleWrapper::class,
   Mockery::mock(GuzzleWrapper::class, function (MockInterface $mock){
      $mock->shouldReceive('post')
      ->andReturn(response()->json([$responseData], 200));
   })
);
```

and following everything I tried is the call to test my controller's function:

```
//Successfully add contacts to list
$this->json('POST', $addContactUri, $input_data, $token);
$this->seeStatusCode(201);
```

Now! Whatever I tried, it's as if the GuzzleWrapper is never mocked, it still does the post and doesn't return status code 200. No matter what I find on google, it never fits with this scenario... Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you using Laravel or any other framework or is this vanilla PHP?

Comment: I am using Laravel and I also use Mockery to mock another client in the same test and it work just fine... Though I don't have to do an expect on a post function for that one

Comment: Try to only use `Http::fake`, but try a hardcoded URL, like `example.com` and use same URL on the real code and see what happens. What is the real output you are getting, hence you know it is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Mocking is based on the container, for `Laravel` to pick up your mocked classes, you should never use the `new` keyword. Instead use the container by using `resolve()`.

```
$client = resolve(GuzzleWrapper::class);
```

This should work with one of the following mock approach where you use `Mockery::mock()`. But the way you are mocking the response, without seing the GuzzleWrapper, i would not expect it to return a Laravel response or else it is custom code.

```
$mockGuzzleClient = Mockery::mock(GuzzleWrapper::class, function (MockInterface $mock){
   $mock->shouldReceive('post')
        ->andReturn(response()->json([$responseData], 200));
});
```

---

The most correct way would to use the `Http` facade. Your call in the controller should look like this.

```
Http::post($uri, $data);
```

The mocking should look like this, in general it seems like you are combining guzzle and `Http` interchangeable in your mocking attempts and that wont fly. If you mock with `Http` use the `Http` facade.

```
Http::fake([
    $uri => Http::response(['your data' => 'response'], 200, []),
]);
```

Comment: I'm not the one who wrote the controller's code and I don't think I'm allowed to change it... is there any way to do it without changing the controller's code?

Comment: No because you can't mock classes that uses the new keyword but $client = resolve(GuzzleWrapper::class); is the same as $client = new GuzzleWrapper(); if you haven't changed the bindings

Comment: but the resolve is needed for mocking

Answer (score 0):

What if you convert the GuzzleWrapper to a dependency? What I mean is to declare the GuzzleWrapper as the private property of the Controller, this way, it would be easier to test the controller: you need to pass the proper GuzzleWrapper to the constructor.

```
class ContactController {
    private GuzzleWrapper $client;

    public function __construct(GuzzleWrapper $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function addContacts(Request $request)
    {
       ...
       $response = $this->client->post($uri, $data);
       if($response->getStatusCode() != 200) { 
          return response()->json("Problem getting data", 500);
       }
       ...
    }
}
```

Once you have done this, it should be easier to test. Then, if you need to test the client, I would recommend either the PHPUnit Mocks or Mockery.

If you can avoid testing the client (maybe you already tested it properly in other places), then I would recommend looking at my composer package https://packagist.org/packages/doppiogancio/mocked-client.